# For which standard deviation is the normal distribution density $0$ up to a given number of decimal places?

Tags: inequality, numerical-methods, exponential-function, normal-distribution

Let $\sigma\in(0,1)$ (a typical choice being $\sigma=0.01$), $$\phi(x):=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb R$$ and $$\psi(x):=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\phi(x+k)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb R.$$

> In a computer program, I need to compute $\psi(x)$ for $x\in(-1,1)$. Obviously, very few summands (somtimes even a single) in the definition of $\psi(x)$ may be sufficient to obtain a sensible approximation.
>
> However, for theoretical purposes, I'd like to determine the interval to which $\sigma$ needs to belong to ensure that $\phi(x\pm k)$ is equal to $0$ up to $n\in\mathbb N$ decimal places. How can we derive these intervals?

Comment: @EricTowers $\phi(x\pm1)$ (with $x\in(-1,1)$). The idea is to show that only the term with $k=0$ in the definition of $\psi(x)$ needs to be considered, since even for $k=\pm1$ the corresponding term is extremely small.

Comment: @EricTowers I think I need to consider $k=\pm2$ as well. So, maybe it's better to state the question with arbitrary $k$.

Comment: Nah.  $\phi(x) = \phi(-x)$, $\phi$ is monotonically strictly increasing on $(-\infty, 0)$ and monotonically strictly decreasing on $(0,\infty)$ so any maximum occurs at some $x \in [0,1)$ and symmetrically at $-x$.  When the domain of $\psi$ was constrained to $x \in [0,1)$, this meant the maximum occurred for $k = 0$ or $k = -1$.  Now the maximum value is unchanged, but it is ambiguous whether it lands in $(-1,0]$ or $[0,1)$; I do wish you would settle on a problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

(This is a complete rewrite, with some small changes to follow the changes to the problem statement.)

Let $\phi(\sigma; x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma} \mathrm{e}^{-x^2/(2 \sigma^2)}$.  $\phi$ is even, $\phi(\sigma; x) = \phi(\sigma; -x)$ for all $x \in \Bbb{R}$, increasing on $(-\infty, 0)$, and decreasing on $(0,\infty)$.

[image: \phi with \sigma = 1/2]

For $x \in (-1/2,1/2]$, $\phi(\sigma; x + k) \geq \phi(\sigma; x + \ell)$ for any integers $k$ and $\ell$ satisfying $|\ell| > |k|$.  For $x \in (-1,-1/2)$, $x+1 \in (-1/2,1/2]$, so $\phi(\sigma; x + 1+ k) > \phi(\sigma; x + \ell)$ for any integers $k$ and $\ell$ satisfying $|\ell| > |k|$.  Symmetrically, for $x \in (1/2,1)$, $x-1 \in (-1/2,1/2]$, so $\phi(\sigma; x - 1+ k) > \phi(\sigma; x + \ell)$ for any integers $k$ and $\ell$ satisfying $|\ell| > |k|$.  To summarize, we might as well take $x \in (-1/2,1/2]$, since every other choice is redundant *and* $\phi(\sigma;x) \geq \phi(\sigma; x+k)$ for all integers $k$.

Choose $x \in (-1/2,1/2]$ and let $k$ range over the nonzero integers.  We have shown $\phi(\sigma; x) \geq \phi(\sigma; x+k)$.

If what we wanted was to find is $\sigma$ such that $\phi(\sigma; x+k) \leq 10^{-n} \phi(\sigma; x)$, so that the terms $\phi(\sigma; x+\ell)$ for $|\ell|>|k|$ did not change the first $n$ nonzero decimal digits of $\phi(\sigma; x)$, we could just use

$$  \frac{\phi(\sigma; x+k)}{\phi(\sigma; x)} = \exp\left( \frac{x^2 - (k+x)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)  < 10^{-n} \text{,}  $$
and solve for $\sigma$ to obtain 
$$  0 < \sigma < \sqrt{\frac{k(k+2x)}{\sqrt{2} \ln(10) n}}  \text{.}  $$

However, you have not asked for $\sigma$ such that the $n$ leading nonzero decimal digits of $\phi(\sigma; x)$ are unchanged by adding $\phi(\sigma; x+k)$ (for some nonzero integer $k$).  You have asked for $\sigma$ such that $\phi(\sigma; x+k) < 10^{-n}$ (for some nonzero integer $k$).  That is, 
$$  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}\sigma} \mathrm{e}^{-(x+k)^2 / (2 \sigma^2)} < 10^{-n}  $$
and this inequality is hopeless.  There is no solving for $\sigma$ here.

So what can we do?

Let $x$ be fixed and see how $\phi$ varies with $\sigma$.

[image: \phi with x = 1/2]

We see that $\phi$ is maximized (with respect to $\sigma$) when $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\sigma} \phi(\sigma; x) = 0$, that is, when
$$  \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2 \sigma ^2}} \left(x^2-\sigma ^2\right)}{\sqrt{2 \pi }\sigma ^4}  = 0  \text{,}  $$
which it is easy enough to see happens when $\sigma = |x|$ (since $\sigma > 0$).

We could choose to binary search for $\sigma \in (0, |x|)$ and then for $\sigma \in (|x|, 1)$ to find one or both $\sigma$ intervals to make $\phi$ small enough for the chosen $x$, $k$, and $n$.

To eliminate half the time, it is worthwhile to ask when (if ever) there is a solution with $\sigma \in (|x|, 1)$, since our plot suggests that $\phi$ is large for $\sigma$ nearer to $1$.  Also, $\phi$ is monotonically decreasing for $\sigma > |x|$, so we can study the minimum of $\phi$ at $\sigma = 1$ as $x$ ranges over $(-1/2,1/2]$.  The minimum value of $\phi$, $1/(\mathrm{e}^{1/8}\sqrt{2\pi}) = 0.352{\dots}$, occurs at $x = 1/2$.  Consequently, no $\sigma > |x|$ can ever give $\phi(\sigma; x) < 10^{-1}$, much less give more zero leading decimal digits.

Therefore, only binary search over the interval $\sigma \in (0,|x|)$ is needed.  For instance, for $x \in (-1/2, 1/2]$, $k \in \Bbb{Z} \smallsetminus \{0\}$, and $n \in \Bbb{N} = \Bbb{Z}_{>0}$,

```
search(float x, k, n){
    // find interval of sigma such that 
    // phi(sigma; x+k) < 10^(-n)
    // the lower bound of sigma is always 0
    // we binary search the upper bound over (0,|x|)
    float epsilon, lowerBound, upperBound
    epsilon = 10^(-10)
    lowerBound, upperBound = 0,|x|
    if phi(upperBound, x+k) > 10^(-n) {
        while upperBound - lowerBound > epsilon 
        // Never pretend to compare floats directly; always compare their difference to "small".
        {
            if phi((1/2)*(upperBound + lowerBound), x+k) > 10^(-n)
            {
                // the midpoint is also an upper bound
                upperBound = (1/2)*(upperBound + lowerBound)
            }
            else
            {
                // the midpoint is also a lower bound
                lowerBound = (1/2)*(upperBound + lowerBound)
            }
            debugPrint lowerBound, upperBound
        }
    }
    return "sigma in [0," + toString((1/2)*(upperBound + lowerBound)) + "] makes phi(sigma; x+k) < 10^(-n)."
```

When run with `search(1/4,1,10)`, ($x = 1/4$, $k = 1$, comparing with $10^{-10}$), we obtain after 32 bisections, `lowerBound`, `upperBound` = $$\frac{777902065}{4294967296},\frac{3111608261}{17179869184}$$ and "sigma in [0,0.18111943...] makes phi(sigma; 1/4 + 1) < 10^(-10)."

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to tackle this problem is to use the probability density function of the standard normal distribution
$$
\Phi(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp(-z^2/2)
$$
where $z = \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}$. Now we are able to solve this for any given value of $\Phi$ and obtain 
$$
\frac{x - \mu}{\sigma} = z = \sqrt{- 2 \ln(\sqrt{2\pi}\Phi)}
$$
Thus we obtain the equation for $\sigma$ for a given mean value $\mu = k$.

Comment: Question's $k$ is not the mean.  In fact, Question's mean is always $0$.  Also, if this could work, you could solve Question's $\phi(x) = 10^{-n}$ for $\sigma$, so do so.

Comment: @EricTowers: Sorry, but I think I don't understand. If we use $x - k$ as argument, we get $\phi(x-k) = \frac{1}{...}exp(- (x - k)^2/(2\sigma^2))$. This is the pdf of the normal distribution $N(k, \sigma^2)$. I understand that the OP likes to get the sum over all integers $k$ in the end. Nevertheless, the OP was explicitly asking for a single term.

Comment: You're ignoring the $\sigma$ in $\dots$ in the denominator, which makes this answer not quite correct.

Comment: @EricTowers: Well, your right. I implicitly assumed, that only $\phi(x) dx$ matters. Thus, I made a change of variable, $x \to z$. Let's see if the OP can shad some light on the actual question. I'm happy to delete my answer, if only $\phi(x)$ is of interest.